# Ghost Blog give class current to menu item for pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, ghost-blog

Is there a way to give class 'current' to active menu item in Ghost Blog. 
I need to give current class to highlight current menu item.

The following is working only for homepage.

```
{{#if current}} nav-current{{/if}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to give a deeper look into the shipped default ghost template. Also the official documentation is a good starting point http://themes.ghost.org/docs/navigation

Comment: @RoKie83 - Wow. Nice anti-answer! I have the same problem and you know what? The default ghost template doesn't highlight pages either. And another thing, the official documentation doesn't mention anything about hightlighting pages. The snippet that mysticalghoul wrote IS from the documentation. So if anyone actually knows how to solve this, please do tell!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem. Works on my local machine but not on the server with Ghost 0.7.1 and no matter which Node version. So it’s not the themes fault.

I contacted the folks in the ghost slack channel but nobody responded to this topic.

So I just handle it via JS on the client side. Not that nice, but this works for me until they fix this issue.

```
$('.nav a').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Comment: Well this is best solution so far. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you saved my evening. You can also change `window.location.href` to `window.localtion.pathname` if you have injected relative links in your menu. You can of course used both at the same time with a simple `||`.

Comment: Did you ever submit a PR to their project repo? I think you should :) This is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. The url you provided in the navigation must be identical to the url of the page. I neglected to add the trailing slash to my url so the if statement returned false.

ie

- `yourblog.com/about` will **not** return true

but

- `yourblog.com/about/` will return true.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I confirm that this saved me a ton of time.  Good answer.

Comment: This is the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/helpers/link_class/) could work.

```
{{link_class for="/about/"}}
```

In my case I managed to do this.

```
{{#foreach navigation}}
    <li class="nav-item{{#match slug 'blog'}} {{link_class for="/blog/"}}{{/match}}">
        ...
    </li>
{{/foreach}}
```